# Can not start nfs-server on centos 7 lxc container

Tags: centos, nfs, lxc

I have `Linux Mint 19.2 Tina` with `4.15.0-54-generic` kernel on host and lxc version `3.0.3`.

Problem is that I can not start `nfs-server` in container.

Steps that I do:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop apparmor
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
$ ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs | grep nfs
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 июл 29 13:48 nfs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 июл 29 13:48 nfs_common
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 июл 29 13:48 nfsd
$ cat /etc/mtab | grep nfs
nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd nfsd rw,relatime 0 0
$ lxc launch images:centos/7 centos-nfs
$ lxc exec centos-nfs bash
# yum install nfs-utils
# systemctl start nfs-server
A dependency job for nfs-server.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details
```

At `systemctl -t mount` I see errors

[image]

UPD

```
# journalctl --no-pager -u nfs-server
Jan 12 13:30:45 centos-nfs systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Jan 12 13:30:45 centos-nfs systemd[1]: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

What could be the problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: Without logs it can only be guessed. What does `journalctl --no-pager -u nfs-server` show?

Comment: Added logs below. Logs tell that `Dependency failed for NFS server` and `journalctl -xe` shows `proc-fs-nfsd.mount` (`Failed to mount NFSD configuration filesystem`) and `var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount` (`Failed to mount RPC Pipe File System`) errors (same as listed in `systemctl -t mount` output)

Comment: If you look at `journalctl -u dev-fs-nfsd.mount`, do you find more info?

Comment: Unfortunately no, `journalctl -u dev-fs-nfsd.mount` shows `-- No entries --`

Comment: Maybe try executing `mount -t nfsd nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd` manually and check any suspect output from `dmesg`.

Comment: # mount -t nfsd nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd
mount: permission denied

Answer (score 0):

That may have something to do with kernel modules. LXC causes problems when trying to load kernel modules inside a container. Try using KVM instead.